# How the L1 distance will be used during training of an image similarity neural network?

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, similarity, transfer-learning, vgg-net

I am implementing a neural network, which finds the similarity between two images, whether they are similar or not.

Reference:https://www.kaggle.com/arpandhatt/siamese-neural-networks/data

Each example contain `([image_1, image_2], label)`. Where label has a value `0` if they are similar and `1` for dissimilar.

The network convnet consists of a series of convolution followed by pooling layers and outputs a feature vector.

In the implementation, they calculate the L1 distance between the encodings and added a dense layer for the final decision.

```
encoded_l = convnet(left_input)
encoded_r = convnet(right_input)

# Getting the L1 Distance between the 2 encodings
L1_layer = Lambda(lambda tensor:K.abs(tensor[0] - tensor[1]))

# Add the distance function to the network
L1_distance = L1_layer([encoded_l, encoded_r])

prediction = Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(L1_distance)
siamese_net = Model(inputs=[left_input,right_input],outputs=prediction)
```

The answers I am looking for:

- How this L1 distance will be used during training the network.
- What are the other options available besides L1 distance for measuring the similarity between the two encodings?

I hope if I can get these answers, I can tweak the network according to my requirements.